# Issue declaring no language in CMake

Tags: unity-game-engine, cmake

I'm trying to integrate cmake into a project that contains a Unity3D project. I want to bypass checks for languages, as the `CMakeLists.txt` file really just houses a custom command that calls Unity3D's build process. I'm aware of the `LANGUAGES NONE` setting in the `project()` command, and also a similar setting in the `set_target_properties()` command. However, neither seem to be working. My complete CMakeLists.txt file is pasted below:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
project (
    "Test-App"
    VERSION
        1.0
    LANGUAGES
        NONE
)   

# For the custom command to be marked as not actually creating a file, 
# you need to set the symbolic property on it
#set_property (
#   SOURCE
#       UNITY_OUTPUT
#   PROPERTY
#       SYMBOLIC
#)  

add_custom_command (
    OUTPUT
        UNITY_OUTPUT
    COMMAND
        /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity -quit -batchmode -buildOSXUniversalPlayer ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Builds/Test-Build.app
    COMMENT
        "Building application..."
)   

add_executable (
    Test-Build
    UNITY_OUTPUT
)   

set_target_properties (
    Test-Build
    PROPERTIES
        LINKER_LANGUAGE
        NONE
)
```

However, in my tereminal output cmake is still complaining that an internal variable has not been set. I get the following output:

```
-- Configuring done
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_NONE_LINK_EXECUTABLE
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: XXX
```

Note that the `Makefile` is still generated and I can still build stuff. I simply want to get rid of this annoying error, to be sure that I fully understand how CMake is operating.

Comment: I've sidestepped the problem by using `add_custom_target()` instead. I would still like to know why I get the error however

Comment: How do you expect to create **executable** (`add_executable (Test-Build UNITY_OUTPUT)`) **without** any **compiler/linker**? If you want `Test-Build` to be "PHONY" target which triggers building of `UNITY_OUTPUT` file, use `add_custom_target(Test-Build DEPENDS UNITY_OUTPUT)` instead.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yep, this was the point of my question. As `Test-Build` is built with a different toolchain (namely Unity3D's), it shouldn't be specified as an **executable**, but as a **PHONY** instead. Thanks for helping me get my head around the semantics a bit better.